# while convert char buffer to string is strdup needed

Tags: c++, string

I have a c++ char buffer in which I read characters from a file, repeatedly. After reading each line, I convert the buffer to a string, for other processing and storage.

```
int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    FILE *f;
    while(1) {
        fgets(buf, MAXBUF, f); //read a line from a file
        string s1(buf);
        string *s2 = new string(buf);
    }
}
```

While converting the buffer to a string, is a copy made automatically, or do I have to explicitly make a copy? ie, should I rewrite the above code as:

```
        string s1(strdup(buf));
        string *s2 = new string(strdup(buf));
```

Comment: A copy is made automatically, but you should just read directly to a string with `std::getline`. And not use `new`. And not use `FILE*`.

Comment: Hopefully you realize that your test code is leaking memory, too.

Comment: Sample code has infinite loop.

Comment: @Ryan: `FILE*` is fine, if I/O performance is an issue.  iostreams are terribly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While converting the buffer to a string, is a copy made automatically, or do I have to explicitly make a copy?

Not only do you not need to call `strdup` to create `s1`, it causes a memory leak.

`strdup` allocates memory for a copy of the input string and returns that memory to you.

The constructor of `string` makes a copy of the input string.

Ergo, the memory allocated by `strdup` is lost in your program.

Don't use it. Just use:

```
string s1(buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to strdup a char* when assigning to an std::string. The string will automatically make its own copy, and handle all the memory management of said copy.